# The procedure entry point vkCmdEndRendering could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: windows, dll, vulkan

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znpDk.png)
My OS is Windows 10, I use Visual Studio 2022. Vulkan SDK was downloaded from the official site, I had never faced problems before.

I had tried

```
for %1 in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %1
```

in command prompt but it didn't help.

`sfc /scannow` showed nothing either.

Event Viewer left me with this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxC8E.png)

Comment: Please add additional details. It is not clear what you're actually doing and what you're actually asking for. I can only guess that you try to run code using the function mentioned in the title. If so, make sure you're using the Vulkan core version that is required for it (1.2).

Comment: Other than the instance/device creation calls, there is no requirement for a Vulkan DLL to expose the entrypoints directly as normal linkable symbols. That's the entire point of the Vulkan loader mechanism - it retrieves the correct function pointer for each function from an instance/device (allowing for layers, etc).

Comment: @SaschaWillems hi, my Vulkan version is 1.3.250.1 should I have installed 1.2 instead?

Comment: @solidpixel yes, but i still see this error :( I have tried different ways of linking libraries but nothing helped

Comment: @solidpixel oh maybe you know, does my problem relate to vulkan-1.dll?

Comment: And what IS your actual problem? Is the error coming from your code or from an application? If it's the former you need to make sure that you request the Vulkan version that actually supports the dynamic rendering extension. If you don't, you won't get a function pointer.

Comment: @SaschaWillems my problem is that the app crashes.  I updated graphic drivers and faced that: Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 Access violation (it refers to `vkCmdEndRendering` function). But I don't even use this function, I call `commandBuffer.endRenderPass()` then `commandBuffer.endRendering()` and can't cath the exception with try-catch... The only extension I use VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation is supported (I checked that before using it)

Answer (score 0):

`commandBuffer.endRenderPass()` sounds like you use the Vulkan C++ bindings. And those just wrap C-api calls. So `commandBuffer.endRenderPass()` calls `vkCmdEndRendering`.

And that function is only available with Vulkan 1.3 (and newer). So in order to use it, you need to request an instance with API version 1.3 (or newer).

Or alternatively you can use the extension function (`vkCmdEndRenderingKHR`) if you enable the `VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering` extension. But then you need to manually load the function pointer.